# WPF Listview item highlighting

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, textbox

I have a listview which contains the customer informations. There is a search text box above the that listview. When you type anything into the textbox then it higlights the matched item in the listview. But , the problem is that it makes search only in the visual side of the listview. It doesn't search in the not scrolled side of the listview(buttom of the listview). My code is below. Please have a look.

```
private void FindListViewItem(DependencyObject obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        ListViewItem lv = obj as ListViewItem;
        if (lv != null)
        {
            HighlightText(lv);
        }
        FindListViewItem(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj as DependencyObject, i));
    }
}

private void HighlightText(Object itx)
{
    if (itx != null)
    {
        if (itx is TextBlock)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("(" +TxtSearch.Text + ")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            TextBlock tb = itx as TextBlock;
            if (TxtSearch.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                string str = tb.Text;
                tb.Inlines.Clear();
                tb.Inlines.Add(str);
                return;
            }
            string[] substrings = regex.Split(tb.Text);
            tb.Inlines.Clear();
            foreach (var item in substrings)
            {
                if (regex.Match(item).Success)
                {
                    Run runx = new Run(item);
                    runx.Background = Brushes.Lime;
                    tb.Inlines.Add(runx);

                    if (tb.IsMouseOver)
                    {
                        tb.IsEnabled = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    tb.Inlines.Add(item);
                    tb.IsEnabled = false;
                }
            }

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(itx as DependencyObject); i++)
            {
                HighlightText(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(itx as DependencyObject, i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also by default ListView control uses virtualization which means that not all of the items are drawn, so your approach will not work in that case.

Comment: Are using an MVVM approach ? Do you have binded view models ?

Comment: @AdrianFaciu then what is your suggestion?

Comment: Does the contents of the list changes when you search ? Or all the items are loaded all the time and you just highlight based on search term ?

Comment: @AdrianFaciu list doesn't change. It is same and it just highlights it based on the search term. I have applied VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" . But, its not so efficient. It takes too many seconds until to highlighting.So, the performance is not so proper.

Comment: Instead of manipulating the OUTPUT that is generated, you should do your highlighting on the displayed item: Search through your List of items and set a variable, that indicates wheter the item matches the search or not. Then just use simple Databinding on that value and you are done without walking through all the possible children of the listview itself. Don't forget to use an observable Collection and fire the NotifyPropertyChanged Event.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the ListView, by default, uses virtualization for its content. This means that the ListViewItems are created when they are needed. If you didn't scroll the ListView, some ListViewItems will not be created and VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount will not be able to return those ListViewItems.

To achieve what you want, you can:

- disable ListView virtualization by setting: `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` on your ListView (not recommended if you have many items in your list).
- you can enforce the creation of the ListViewItem which are not visible by calling `IItemContainerGenerator.GenerateNext` and `IItemContainerGenerator.PrepareItemContainer` (not recommended at all). (also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630124/forcing-wpf-to-create-the-items-in-an-itemscontrol))
- find a better logic to highlight your ListViewItems :) (recommended). (for example search on your collection for the items you want to highlight instead of searching on the UI elements that are only displaying your items. Then mark the items found as highlighted and base on this, display the ListViewItems accordingly (with a different template or style))

Comment: I have applied your first solution. It works but not so efficeiently :D As you said , there are too many items in my list,therefore it doesn't work properly. I couldn't apply the second one :) The last one is that I dont want to make it :)

Comment: +1, recommended way would be to follow a different approach to highlight the items, disabling virtualization usually asks for trouble

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways. Here is one way that i think would work in your scenario and partially with your code and still use virtualization.

Use a data template for the list view item, and create an event handler for loaded event, something like:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded"/>
      </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

In the OnLoaded event handler call your HighlightText method on the sender:

```
HighlightText(sender)
```

In order to trigger the loaded event you'll need to refresh the list view each time the search string will change. Something like `ListView.Items.Refresh()` should do it.

You could improve this a bit by adding a small timer on the search text changed, so the user will be able to finish typing when it's searching for something.

There are other, more elegant ways to handle this, but for your case i think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to my Comment:

Use a Property and a Observable Collection and directly filter on that Collection.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Entry> MyCollection {get;set;}

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<Entry>();
        MyCollection.Add(new Entry() { Name = "Test" });
        MyCollection.Add(new Entry() { Name = "ABCD" });
        MyCollection.Add(new Entry() { Name = "TESTABC" });
        MyCollection.Add(new Entry() { Name = "BCDtest" });

        this.MyListView.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void searchTerm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        String term = ((TextBox)sender).Text;

        foreach (Entry entry in this.MyCollection)
        {
            if (entry.Name.Contains(term))
                entry.Highlight();
            else
                entry.UnHighlight();
        }

    }
}

public class Entry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Color BGColor { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush BGBrush
    {
        get
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(this.BGColor);
        }
    }

    public Entry()
    {
        this.UnHighlight();
    }

    public void Highlight()
    {
        this.BGColor = Colors.Yellow;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("BGBrush");
    }

    public void UnHighlight()
    {
        this.BGColor = Colors.White;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("BGBrush");
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }


}
```

along with

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="searchTerm" KeyUp="searchTerm_KeyUp"></TextBox>
        <ListView Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Background="{Binding BGBrush}" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

And you are done. No need to manually touch the listview at any time. (To Increase Performance: For the Raising of the PropertyChanged Event you may want to add a check, if its really changing, or if it has been set to white from white etc.)

Comment: Isn't this going to highlight the whole item, irrelevant of the search term ? As i understood the OP was trying to select only the parts that are matching the search term.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu he wrote `then it higlights the matched item in the listview`. So i think whole item is what he wants.